# Method invocation may produce NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Eu estou usando geocoder para transformar o endereço do edit text em Longitude e Latitude. Ai ele ta fazendo certinho e salvando no banco a lat e lng, mas ele da uma exception que nao causa nenhum problema no app, mas fica dando o erro na tela e tenho que apertar ok toda vez, e ele diz que é por causa do adresses.get(0) que fica dando um nullpointerException, como ajeito?

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(stringLocal, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    double longitude = address.getLongitude();
    double latitude = address.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 4):

A causa é que você não trata a exceção no s eu `try/catch`. A variável `addresses` vai ficar nula e o método vai continuar executando.

Uma possível codificação correta para esse código seria:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(stringLocal, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //mostra mensagem de erro
    return; //sai do método já que não consegue calcular 
}

Address address = addresses.get(0);
double longitude = address.getLongitude();
double latitude = address.getLatitude();
```

Outra possibilidade seria:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(stringLocal, 1);
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    double longitude = address.getLongitude();
    double latitude = address.getLatitude();    
} catch (IOException e) {
    //mostra mensagem de erro
    return; //sai do método já que não consegue calcular 
}
```

Não se esqueça que também pode ocorrer um erro se a lista não trouxer nenhum elemento. Então é sempre bom verificar se ela não é vazia. Exemplo:

```
public void mostrarCoordenadas() {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(stringLocal, 1);
        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            double longitude = address.getLongitude();
            double latitude = address.getLatitude();
            //exibe latitude e longitude
        } else {
            //mostra erro amigável
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //mostra erro amigável
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!